# Haskell parser error in where clause

Tags: syntax, haskell

What is wrong with `rs` definition in first where section?

```
palindrome :: [a] -> [a]

palindrome xs = con xs rs
    where con a b = rev (rev a []) b
        rs = rev xs                        -- here
        where rev [] rs = rs
            rev (x:xs) rs = rev xs (x:rs)
```

I'm just learning Haskell but its syntax rules confuse me. The error message is

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( pelindrome.hs, interpreted )

pelindrome.hs:5:8: parse error on input `rs'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your indentation was wrong and i think you can only have one `where` in there (i could be very well wrong. I'm not a haskell guy). There was also a argument missing for the call to `rev` (an empty list):

```
palindrome :: [a] -> [a]
palindrome xs = con xs rs
    where con a b = rev (rev a []) b
          rs = rev xs []                       -- here
          rev [] rs = rs
          rev (x:xs) rs = rev xs (x:rs)

main = print (palindrome "hello")
```

Prints out:

```
"helloolleh"
```

I'm going to try to understand it now. Anyway, have fun!

Edit: Makes perfect sense to me now. I think that's the right version. For Haskell indentation rules, read [Haskell Indentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Indentation)

Comment: You are right, rs must start in same column as con in previous line. It is weird rule.

Comment: Not weird: same syntactic level -> same indentation

Comment: you can use braces to "break" out that rule

Answer (score 0):

@litb: You can rewrite con in way

```
palindrome :: [a] -> [a]
palindrome xs = con xs rs
    where con [] b = b
          con (x:xs) b = x:con xs b
          rs = rev xs []                       -- here
          rev [] rs = rs
          rev (x:xs) rs = rev xs (x:rs)
```

which is how ++ is implemented in prelude. My previous version is way how to write it in non lazy functional or logical languages in tail call fashion (e.g. Erlang).

Comment: I thought (++) was defined as (++) = flip $ foldr (:) - that's how I would've written it anyways.